# MouseDown event for multiple buttons

Tags: c#

Basically, I've named my mousedown event to be LBTNDOWN, and I've linked the event together with 3 other buttons. I want to make a switch case for each button when it's pressed down, it does something. And I'll also be making a separate mouseup event that does something when the mouse is released, but I'm already stuck at mousedown.

I've tried almost everything and researched so many solutions however it doesn't work! I'm desperate as I have to submit this project tomorrow omg!

```
    private void LBTNDOWN(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        ///Code
        switch (e.Button)
        {
            case btnCFL:  
                txtbox1.text = '1';
                break;
            case btnCFR:
                txtbox1.text = '2';
                break;
        }
    }
```

I expected the output to be for example when button CFL is pressed down, textbox1 will change to 1, then when button CFR is pressed down, textbox1 will change to 2.

Comment: Look at you Visual Studio. It clearly says that _"A switch expression or case label **must** be a bool, char, string, integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type"_. But nobody ever reads exception messages, I know :(

Comment: I totally don't pay attention to that... It is my fault haha, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think "switch (e.Button)" is well supported.

Please try below code:

```
    private void LBTNDOWN(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){

    ///Code
        switch ((sender as Button).Text){
            case "CFL":  
                txtbox1.text = '1';
                break;
            case "CFR":
                txtbox1.text = '2';
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Default case should be included as a good habit");
                break;
        }
    }
```

- If text cannot distinguish these buttons, you may use tag property of button instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! It sort of works but still I encountered some problems which result in the output not showing. I've just decided to do the mousedown event one by one for the buttons, although it's a lot less effective but I've got no choice. Thanks again!! :)